# How to use AlertDialog ShowEvent to grab focus of an edittext in the dialog?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

The following code display the dialogue but does not grab focus. How can it be altered to open the soft touch keyboard without calling the input method manager like an ape?

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);  
AlertDialog.Builder odomoter_dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
AlertDialog dialog = odomoter_dialog.Create();
                dialog.ShowEvent += (d, arg) =>
                {
                    editText.RequestFocus();
                };
                dialog.Show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since @Max only provides the Java code for traditional Android app, here I write this answer to convert it to C# for Xamarin.Android app.

For example:

```
var odomoter_dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
odomoter_dialog.SetView(Resource.Layout.DiaologView);
var dialog = odomoter_dialog.Create();
dialog.Window.SetSoftInputMode(Android.Views.SoftInput.StateAlwaysVisible);
dialog.Show();
```

The `DiaologView` is like this by my side:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Please enter your name:" />\

  <EditText
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So it seems like you have to create a custom layout to avoid using the `InputMethodManager`...

Comment: @Michael Gabay，yes I set a layout for dialog，cause I thought you want to add a edittext to the dialog in your code. This only works when there is an editttext, otherwise we need to use 'InputMethodManager' as you said.

Answer (score 1):

to show keyboard right away add this line after dialog.show();

```
odomoter_dialog.show()
   .getWindow()
   .setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

If u need to set the focus, you also need to do it after dialog.Show(); 
p.s. Dont forget to user dialog.findviewbyid for your focus view

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); 
        View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R*, null, false);
 
        builder.setView(viewInflated);

        builder.setPositiveButton();
      builder.show().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);